# Find all tags of multi-attribute class bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I know to find all occurrences of a class with one attribute is the following.

```
soup.find_all('a', class_='className')
```

But this does not get all tags for a class such as below.

```
soup.find_all('a', class_='class Name')
```

How can I find all tags of a beautiful soup object that has a multi-attribute class such as "class_='class Name'"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider html like this.

```
<div class="one two">
this
</div>
<div class="one">
that
</div>
```

If you can be confident of the formatting of the 'one two' in the `class` attribute then it can be done as simply as in the following code. Otherwise, you would need to arrange to reformat.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('emh.htm').read(), 'lxml')
>>> def accept(item):
...     return item=='one two'
... 
>>> 
>>> soup.find_all('div', class_=accept)
[<div class="one two">
this
</div>]
```

Each time `find_all` sees a `class` attribute it invokes the `accept` function, which compares the attribute with the string constant 'one two'. If the function returns `True` then `find_all` returns the associated element, in this case a `div`.

Comment: Hi Bill. I had trouble understanding the implementation that you used. I was able to find my answer in the duplicate posted by the moderators. I ended up using a combination of css selectors and tag attributes to get the job done. Thank you for your help.